# How do you add a local R package using Nix package manager

Tags: r, nix

Let's say that I have a local R package that lives at `/home/placey/messyverse.tar.gz`

I'd like to start up a nix shell that contains my package as well as ggplot. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we need to create a nix package that contains the necessary information for your local package.

Lets call it

`messverse.nix`

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

{
  messverse = rPackages.buildRPackage rec {
      name = "messverse";
      version = "0.1";
      src = /home/placey/messverse.tar.gz;
      buildInputs = with rPackages; [
        R
        stringr
      ];
  };
}
```

Then in the same folder we will create the `default.nix` that defnes what is needed for the nix shell.

`default.nix`

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
with import ./messyverse.nix;
{
    myProject = stdenv.mkDerivation {
      name = "myProject";
      version = "1";
      src = if pkgs.lib.inNixShell then null else nix;

      buildInputs = with rPackages; with messyverse; [
        R
        ggplot2
        messyverse
      ];
    };
}
```

now we can execute 
`nix-shell .`

and we have a shell which contains R & our locally specified R package!